# Long tick labels getting cut off in plotly.js chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, axes, plotly

Is it possible to give more room for tick labels in [plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript)? Long labels in my charts are getting cut off.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="plot"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var data = [{
  type: 'bar',
  x: [20, 14, 23],
  y: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'a looooooooong string'],
  orientation: 'h'
}];

var layout = {
  title: 'Bar Chart'
};

Plotly.newPlot('plot', data, layout);
```

I can't see how to do this in the [API for y-axes tick settings](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-yaxis-ticks).

Given the nature of my charts, I need to use a horizontal orientation. So a solution I can't use is a vertical orientation with ticks rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: auto-margin is planned addition. follow this issue https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/296

Answer (score 21):

**Update**: plotly added support for automargins (see https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/2243), via the .*axis*.automargin configuration option.

To use, you'd change:

```
var layout = {
  title: 'Bar Chart'
};
```

to:

```
var layout = {
  title: 'Bar Chart',
  yaxis: {
    automargin: true
  }
};
```

For more information, see https://plot.ly/javascript/axes/

**Original Answer**:
You can adjust the margins of plotly charts to give yourself some more space. For instance, change:

```
var layout = {
  title: 'Bar Chart'
};
```

to

```
var layout = {
  title: 'Bar Chart',
  margin: {
    l: 200
  }
};
```

you can read more about adjusting margins here: https://plot.ly/javascript/setting-graph-size/ 
and overall layout options here: https://plot.ly/javascript/#layout-options

Answer (score 2):

You can also set margin dynamically, based on label length:

```
var maxLabelLength = d3.max(data, d => d3.max(d.y, label => label.length));
const letterWidth = 7;
var layout = {
  title: 'Bar Chart',
  margin:{
    l: maxLabelLength * letterWidth
  }
};
```

Comment: with pure JS: `var maxLabelLength = Math.max.apply(null, y.map(label => label.length));`